# Decryption Is Not Working >>>

Tags: delphi, encryption

I've used this simple code that encrypts plain text. Then I tried to decrypt it using the same encrypting method but reversed in encryption section. There's a multiplication process that I don't know how to reverse it in the decryption code.

Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: String;
  count, ilength: Integer;
begin
  s := edit1.Text;
  ilength := Length(s);
  FOR count := 1 to ilength do
  begin
    s[count] := chr(ord(s[count]) * 4 + 1); // Encoding
  end;
  Label1.caption := s;
  // Display encoded text
  // Decoding section
  // This will probably be placed in another procedure.
  FOR count := 1 to ilength do
  begin
    s[count] := chr(ord((s[count]) / 4) - 1);
    // Here I Get An Error ! Please Help Guys, Thanks
  end;
end;
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: Security is _hard_.  Don't invent your own crypto

Comment: @Slaks [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2008 Incompatible types

Comment: @Slaks ,,I Don't Get It ?? Please Clarify What You're Trying To Say ?

Comment: @Billo.S Please review the edit I made to your question. 1. I formatted the code. 2. I cleaned up the language, removing those odd commas that you seem so keen on. 3. I converted all your mid-sentence capital letters to lower case. Please can you make sure that all future posts are correctly formatted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes sir, sorry for that, students can do nothing but bow for their respective teachers, and I think you are a great teacher. Thanks for help I will be avoiding those mistakes in the future. The fact is i'm really new here and English is not my native language, thanks a lot for your effort to put back on the right path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to perform integer division. In Delphi you do that with `div`. The `/` operator is for floating point division. Looking at the code, you are trying to reverse this calculation:

```
ord(s[count]) * 4 + 1
```

You reverse that like this:

```
(ord(s[count]) - 1) div 4
```

However, your algorithm will not work. Consider what happens when you encrypt 64 and 128. You multiply by 4 to get 256 and 512 respectively. Then add one to get 257 and 513. Then you store back to an 8 bit data type and lose the higher order bytes. And so both characters are encoded  to the value 1.

I'm assuming that you are using 8 bit text. But if you are using 16 bit text, your algorithm still fails in an exactly analogous fashion. Your proposed algorithm is not reversible.

I urge you to find an off-the-shelf encryption algorithm rather than trying to write your own. Encryption is hard to get right.

Comment: It could be made to work if the factor 4 were replaced by an odd number, though, since those are invertible modulo 2^8. But I fully agree with you last sentence.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But this part of your answer I think I didn't get it correctly probably "Consider what happens when you encrypt 64 and 128. You multiply by 4 to get 256 and 512 respectively. Then add one to get 257 and 513. Then you store back to an 8 bit data type and lose the higher order bytes. And so both characters are encoded to the value 1.

I'm assuming that you are using 8 bit text. But if you are using 16 bit text" what is 8 bit text and 16 bit text ? I tried large amounts of data and it decrypted it perfectly !

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: In that case you have 16 bit text. Try your algo on 2^14 and 2^15.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried encrypting 2^14 which is (16384) and 2^15 which is (32768)(if that's what you meant) and then decrypted them , it worked perfectly , I think you can try it too it's awesome ! it encrypts anything and decrypts it !

Comment: try the single characters with those ordinal values. Write them in code as chr(16384) and chr(32768).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21813/discussion-between-billo-s-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 5):

You're using `/` to do a division. This returns a floating point. use `DIV` instead to return an integer.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera It's incomplete though. Replacing `/` with `div` is not enough.